# How to add info icon on textinputlayout when floating label is raised

Tags: android, xamarin.android

How to add info icon when floating label is raised just beside hint.
Like this http://prntscr.com/nlipdn

I have tried with below code:
when focus change on edittext.I added info icon.But I don't know how to set info icon beside floating label. I have added but it's not positioning proper.

```
 public void OnFocusChange(View v, bool hasFocus)
 {
            ImageView _infoView=null;
            if (_infoView != null)
            {
                _songTitleLayout.RemoveView(_infoView);
                _infoView = null;
            }

            if (v==_eSongTitle)
            {
                if(hasFocus)
                {
                    int length= _songTitleLayout.Hint.Length;
                    _infoView = new ImageView(this);
                    _infoView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.MoreInfo);
                    _songTitleLayout.AddView(_infoView);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add your code! What you tried?

Comment: @VanjaraSweta Are you using the TextInputLayout ?

Comment: @Dilmah Yes.Have you know about how to do this.If you have any alternative.you can suggest me.I'll try to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I add a `margin` before you add the `_inforView` by using code below, you can change the values to adjust the margin and size of image:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams paramsw = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(40,40);
paramsw.SetMargins(200,0,0,0);

CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams lp = new 
CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams(paramsw);

txtlayoutusername.AddView(_infoView,0,lp);
```

Here is all the codes I tested:

This is the code in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    TextInputLayout txtlayoutusername;
    EditText txtusername;
    ImageView _infoView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        txtlayoutusername = FindViewById<TextInputLayout>(Resource.Id.textuernameInputLayout);
        txtusername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtusername);

        txtusername.FocusChange += (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) =>
        {


            if (_infoView != null)
            {
                txtlayoutusername.RemoveView(_infoView);
                _infoView = null;
            }

            if (sender == txtusername)
            {
                if (txtusername.IsFocused)
                {
                    int length = txtlayoutusername.Hint.Length;
                    _infoView = new ImageView(this);
                    _infoView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ttt);

                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams paramsw = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(40,40);
                    paramsw.SetMargins(200,0,0,0);

                    CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams lp = new CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams(paramsw);

                    txtlayoutusername.AddView(_infoView,0,lp);
                }
            }
        };
    }  
}
```

Here is code in Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textuernameInputLayout">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtusername"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation = "horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/textpasswordInputLayout">          

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtpassword"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"             
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The result:

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks.Let me try.

Comment: @VanjaraSweta No, problem. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hello,I have done but getting extra space http://prntscr.com/nmbbyo . In your code too

Comment: @VanjaraSweta Add a -40 margin to bottom would fix it. `paramsw.SetMargins(200,0,0,-40);`

Comment: Yes it's Worked.Thanks a lot :) . Yeah I have done finally :)

Comment: but I have a one question.I have to sepcify specific margin.Can we set from length ?

Comment: And Again I have another question.Can we set red astrik. http://prntscr.com/nlipdn Like this on textinputlayout.I have find out solution.but not getting

Comment: @VanjaraSweta Yes, you can calculate the length of string. And I think  red astrik. is the same as imageView.

Comment: But I want to red astrik on Hint too on edittext.I have tried with Spannable String.But It's doesn't work with TextInputLayout.